# Macro that runs all buttons of the same name sequentially

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a workbook with multiple tabs, one tab called "summary" contains a series of rows, each with a designated button, which is assigned a macro where if clicked, it updates additional sheets and copies the values of the row in the summary tab and the additional sheets, with updated data.

I need to create a macro that would click that button for each row sequentially (without actually having to code each one since it's over a hundred of them and may change).

The code that underlies the button for each row looks like this:

```
Sub SubmitData()
    Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DetailedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim columnRange_status As Range
    
    Set inputSheet = Worksheets("Summary")
    Set DetailedSheet = Worksheets("DetailedTab")
    Set outputSheet = Worksheets("OutputFile")

    Set columnRange_status = inputSheet.Range("SubmitButton_Status")
       
    ' Condition before submitting
    If inputSheet.Range("W" & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row).Value = "Pass" Then

    lastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    
    DetailedSheet.Range("C2").Value = inputSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row).Value

    With inputSheet
        'Date
        outputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date
        'Enligsh Short Name
        outputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = .Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row).Value
            End With
            
        With DetailedSheet
  
    'Quarterly Data used by Model - Quarter minus 1
        outputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 291).Value = .Range("AC9").Value

        End With
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox "Cannot submit. Condition is not met yet."
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub MasterBtn_Click()
For Each OLEObject In Worksheets(1).OLEObjects
    If TypeName(OLEObject.Object) = "Submit" Then OLEObject.Object = True
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than simulating clicks on all the buttons in the worksheet, you can take a more direct approach in code.

Loop through column W on `inputSheet` and check for cells that:

- Contain a button
- Its value = "Pass"
For those qualifying cells, update `DetailedSheet` and `outputSheet` accordingly, without needing to simulate a button click.

Comment: Checking `TypeName(OLEObject.Object) = "Submit"` would never evaluate to True, since "Submit" is not a type name. Do you mean `TypeName(OLEObject.Object) = "CommandButton" `

Comment: Looks like your buttons may be Forms buttons/shapes and not activeX though?

Comment: I agree with @taller_ExcelHome, there's no need to click the buttons.  Just execute the code the button would have executed if it was clicked.  Way faster, too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code within SubmitData(), it looks like you're using buttons from Form Controls. Accordingly, try the following...

### **SubmitData**

```
Sub SubmitData(Optional buttonName As Variant)

    If IsMissing(buttonName) Then
        buttonName = Application.Caller
    End If
    
    'the rest of your code goes here
    'from this point forward replace every occurrence of Application.Caller with buttonName
    '
    '
    '
    
    Debug.Print buttonName
    
End Sub
```

### **MasterBtn_Click**

Let's assume that Column J contains your buttons, try the following code...

```
Sub MasterBtn_Click

    Dim btn As Button
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
        For Each btn In .Buttons
            If Not Intersect(btn.TopLeftCell, .Columns("J")) Is Nothing Then 'change the column reference accordingly
                Application.Run btn.OnAction, btn.Name
            End If
        Next btn
    End With

End Sub
```